# How to make popup in a loop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, popup

I'm trying to make popup in a loop in React, but I don't know how to open only one triggered element.

```
this.props.Videos.map((video) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={this.onClick}>
            <img src="https://blog.xenproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Testing.jpg" alt=""/>
            <h3>Text</h3>
            <div style={{display: this.state.videoPopup === true ? "block" : "none"}}>
                <video data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": ""}] }'
               className="video-js vjs-default-skin"
               controls>
               </video>
           </div>
        </div>
    );
})) : null
```

OnClick changes state like this:

```
    this.setState({
        videoPopup: !this.state.videoPopup
    });
```

Comment: Maybe save video objects in an array in state, then get the index of each video in the map function and use it to change the videoPopup for the relevant video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store in state a falsey initial video index that won't automatically be selected (null, undefined).  Create a click handler that accepts a video index as a parameter and then set that to state.  In the render function use the fact that you have `this.state.videoIndex` to test if it equals the currently being rendered video div and set its attribute accordingly.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    videoIndex: null, // falsey value
  }
}

videoClickHandler = index => this.setState(prevState => ({ videoIndex: prevState.videoIndex ? null : index})); // if truthy videoIndex, set null, else, set index

this.props.Videos.map((video, index) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => this.videoClickHandler(index)}> // pass index to callback
      ...
      <div style={{display: this.state.videoIndex === index ? "block" : "none"}}> // test if state value equals current index
      ...
    </div>
  );
})) : null
```

Comment: It helped me, but I have some issues. I can't close this popup. I mean that function inside this map doesn't change state. Apart from that when I change video from one to another, first video isn't stopping. Do you have any ideas how to repair that?

Comment: Updated, check now.